# Bootstrap 4 multiple modal

Tags: javascript, html, modal, bootstrap-4

estou fazendo uma pagina que usa modal em cima de modal (clica no botão, abre modal e quando clica no botão dentro desse modal abre outro).

Estava fazendo isso com bootstrap 3.3.7, PORÉM agora migrei para a versão 4 e onde eu tinha modal sobre modal agora esta funcionando estranho, o modal secundário esta abrindo atras do primario...

Não encontrei nada na internet a fora com múltiplos modais do bootstrap 4, apenas do 3...

tive que usar um css p/ aparecer os modais

```
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.modal-backdrop .fade .in {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

tentei usar isso..

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
            var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
            $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
            }, 0);
        });
```

tente praticamente tudo mas da versao 3 :/

Answer (score 0):

Use este código:

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
   var modS = $('.modal').not($(this)),
       modZ = 0;
   modS.each(function(){
      var zIdx = $(this).css('z-index');
      if(zIdx >= modZ){
         modZ = parseInt(zIdx)+1;
      }
   });
   $(this).css('z-index', modZ);
});
```

Ele irá fazer com que a última modal aberta tenha `z-index` maior do que as outras.

**Código comentado:**

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){ // detecta abertura da model
   var modS = $('.modal').not($(this)), // seleciona todas as modais menos a que foi aberta
       modZ = 0; // variável para comparar os z-index das modais e armazenar a que tiver o maior
   modS.each(function(){ // loop nas modais
      var zIdx = $(this).css('z-index'); // modal atual do loop
      if(zIdx >= modZ){ // vejo se o z-index da modal do loop é maior ou igual do que a variável
         modZ = parseInt(zIdx)+1; // se for maior ou igual, somo +1 ao valor 
      }
   });
   $(this).css('z-index', modZ); // aplico o valor ao z-index da modal aberta
});
```